# How can I automatically extract attributes in a Shapefile for a group of points (latitude and longitude) using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, latitude-longitude

I have a Shapefile for the City of Montreal with buildings' attributes. I also have the coordinates (Latitude and Longitude) of a group of points and I want to extract the attributes for each point.

My idea is to follow steps like this:

1. import a .txt or CSV file which includes the location of the points into the QGIS.
2. Extract the attributes of each point from the shapefile.
3. export data into a new csv or txt file.

I am a beginner with QGIS and I don't know something like this is doable using QGIS API or there is another solution for it.

Comment: What have you tried? Try `Intersect` or `Join attribute by location` then export output as a text file.

Comment: I tried the join attribute by location and it works. But the problem is that for a big region like the whole Montreal City with many points it takes more than two weeks to finish it and I am looking for a faster solution.

Comment: How many points? How did you import the points, "Add delimited text layer"? I would try exporting them to a geopackage then use the geopackage in the join instead of the text layer.

Comment: Almost 50000 points. Yes, I used the "Add delimited text layer" to import the CSV file. So you think by exporting a geopackage it can be faster? I will try it.

Comment: What `geometric predicate` do you use in Spatial Join, `intersect`? How many are the buildings?

Comment: Just tried with 50k points and 17k polygons both in geopackage format (with spatial indexes) and spatial join finished in ~5 seconds. The area is about 51k square km (~20k sq miles)

Comment: I use "intersect". There are 513235 buildings in the shapefile. I just imported a new CSV file with only two points and used the join attribute by location and it took 15 minutes to finish it. I will export points into the geopackage, maybe it can be faster.